# PROCV Excel - Utilizações de conexões

Tags: microsoft-excel

É possível utilizar as conexões com outras planilhas em um PROCV ?

Ex:

Adicionei uma conexão a outra planilha que uso. Nela existe colunas. Consigo aplicar um PROCV ou alguma outra formula para consumir dados ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc precisa usar as conexões ou poderia apenas usar um caminho relativo? Porque o Procv pode ser usado buscando de outras planilhas/arquivos da mesma forma que se utiliza em uma mesma planilha.

Comment: Se optar usar uma conexão com outro arquivo pode usar query diretamente no arquivo buscando os dados que queira. Se colocar na pergunta os tipos de dados e um exemplo dos dados que precisa extrair creio que terá uma ajuda mais precisa.

Comment: @Evert, bom dia.

Quero usar conexões. Pode me ajudar com a questão das Querys?

Eu vou ter 1 número na plan A que vou utilizar como chave de busca na plan B. E quero retornar o valor de uma coluna.
Igual o PROCV mas através de conexões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que está usando conexões, sugiro usar o *Microsoft Query*, da seguinte maneira:

Tenho uma planilha (dados.xlsx) com seus dados, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na sua planilha de resultado (resultado.xlsx), onde deseja que apareça a sua pesquisa faça os seguintes passos:

1. Insira uma *Query* conforme abaixo:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Selecione a opção *Excel Files* e clique 'Ok':
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Selecione seu arquivo de dados:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Caso não apareça o nome da aba/planilha clique em Opções e marque a opção "Tabelas do Sistema". Selecione a planilha e clique na seta para a direita, conforme sequência na imagem abaixo:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Após clicar em "Avançar", selecione a coluna que deverá ser filtrada e selecione o texto/número para o filtro, clicando em "Avançar" terá a possibilidade de classificar o seu resultado por determinada coluna:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. Avançando novamente poderá escolher em qual planilha e em qual célula colocar os dados:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

8. "Ok" e seus dados estarão na sua planilha de resultado. Ao inserir um novo dado na sua planilha de Dados, vá até sua planilha de Resultados e clique em Atualizar para buscar novos dados:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Para automatizar esse processo, poderá tentar "gravar" uma macro e depois editar para suprir sua demanda criando novas conexões automatizadas.

**EDIÇÃO 1**

Para inserir um critério poderia usar a seguinte função (*Sub*) abaixo:

```
Sub busca_dados_externos()

Dim CRITERIO As String

    CRITERIO = Range("A2").Text

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=C:\Users\m362168\OneDrive\Projetos\Budhi\Excel\Query\dados.xlsx;DefaultDir=C:\Users\m362168\OneDrive\Projet" _
        ), Array("os\Budhi\Excel\Query;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;") _
        ), Destination:=Range("$B$2")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT `Plan1$`.teste, `Plan1$`.descricao, `Plan1$`.valor" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `C:\Users\m362168\OneDrive\Projetos\Budhi\Excel\Query\dados.xlsx`.`Plan1$` `Plan1$`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (`Plan1$`.teste='" & CRITERIO & "')" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "ORDER BY `Plan1$`.d" _
        , "escricao, `Plan1$`.valor")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Tabela_Consulta_de_Excel_Files_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C10").Select
End Sub
```

> Claro que pode-se colocar todas as variáveis (ARQUIVO, CAMINHO, COLUNAS, CRITÉRIO, DESTINO etc) de forma dinâmica, para ter uma função mais completa.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Evert, consigo colocar o critério como =$A2 ?

Tentei aqui e não funcionou

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. A partir daí sugiro que teste a macro e coloque as variáveis de forma dinâmica para que os dados sejam inseridos no local a ser definido.

Comment: Deu certo ai @KennedyMota?

Comment: Eu estou utilizando as conexões agora, mas não da forma ideal que eu queria. Mas já esta resolvido.

Obrigado